# Recursion error maximum stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

I have some JavaScript code that works recursively. When I set the code to loop for up to 15 times, it works fine, but when the code loops 16 times or more I have the error "Maximum call stack size exceeded". I have looked into this error, and seen come across the tail call elimination method to prevent this error, but this does not seem to work, and I'm not sure if I have implemented it correctly.

Here is the code with the tail call elimination method:

```
function solve(board, i, unchangeables) {
  function tail(board, i, unchangeables) {
    if(i < 17) {
      board[i] = 1
      if(checkValid(board, i)) {
        i += 1
        /*while(i in unchangeables) {
          i += 1
        }*/
        return solve(board, i, unchangeables)
      } else {
        while(checkValid(board, i) == false) {
          if (board[i] < 9) {
            board[i] += 1
          } else {
            board[i] = ''
            i -= 1
            while(i in unchangeables) {
              i -= 1
            }
            return solve(board, i, unchangeables)
          }
        }
        i += 1
        return solve(board, i, unchangeables)
      }
    } else {
      return board
    }
  }
  return tail(board, i, unchangeables)
}
```

Here is the code without the tail call elimination method:

```
function solve(board, i, unchangeables) {
    if(i < 17) {
      board[i] = 1
      if(checkValid(board, i)) {
        i += 1
        /*while(i in unchangeables) {
          i += 1
        }*/
        return solve(board, i, unchangeables)
      } else {
        while(checkValid(board, i) == false) {
          if (board[i] < 9) {
            board[i] += 1
          } else {
            board[i] = ''
            i -= 1
            while(i in unchangeables) {
              i -= 1
            }
            return solve(board, i, unchangeables)
          }
        }
        i += 1
        return solve(board, i, unchangeables)
      }
    } else {
      return board
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It's not very clear to me.

Comment: I don't think that's actually "tail call elimination." You're adding an extra function call, not eliminating one. That would make your call stack longer, not shorter. Call elimination would be more like if you put in a `for` or `while` loop in place of your `if`, and then every place you're doing `return solve` you reset variable values and then did a `continue` to skip to the next iteration of the loop.